# how to use action filter when i have 2 method with same name with different protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce, action-filter

I am using actin filter in ASP.NET MVC, now if there is only 1 action method then i haven't issue but when there is 2 method with same name just protocol is different like http get and post then how can i use filter?

Please advice!

Action method:-

```
[httpget]
public actionresult home()
{
 return view();
}

[httppost]
public actionresult home()
{
return null;
}
```

Action filter code:

```
public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(HomeController) &&
                      (actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("home")))
            {
                return new Filter[] 
                    { 
                        new Filter(this._actionFilter, FilterScope.Action, null)
                    };
            }

            return new Filter[] { };

        }

public  void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {{ "Controller", "xyz" }, 
                                      { "Action", "abc" } });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

See when i run this code i have found every time this code run on httpget but i want to run filter on httppost method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this in your GetFilter method:

```
if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(HomeController) &&
                  (actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("home")) && controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if it has `HttpPost` attribute or not, means `HttPost` is called by client or `HttpoGet`:

```
public  void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
  try
  {
   var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
   var actionParams = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters
   var actionParamsTypes = actionParams.Cast<ParameterDescriptor>()
                                       .Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();
   var controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();            
   var actionMethodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionName,
                                                actionParamsTypes, 
                                                null);            
   var IsHttpPost = actionMethodInfo.IsDefiend(typeof(HttpPostAttribute),false);

   if(IsHttpPost) // checking if it is HttpPost
     {
        // do something
     }
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }

}
```